# Point to localhost in a different machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I have a netflix eureka server running in a machine with ip:

```
136.144.28.122
```

and in that machine the eureka server runs at:

```
http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Then I have a program that is annotated with:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
```

and I dont know how to to write the ip address so it points to `localhost:8761` that runs in     `136.144.28.122`

This is my `application.yml` file:

eureka:
client:
serviceUrl:
defaultZone: http://136.144.28.122:8761/eureka/

I dont think `http://136.144.28.122:8761/eureka/` is correct because the client service doesnt register in the eureka server.

Comment: Maybe you should make your `Eureka` server run on `http://136.144.28.122:8761/eureka`

Comment: Could you please show me how?

Comment: Check out this useful tutorial, may be it helps: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka

Comment: Let's try something like `server: host: 136.144.28.122 `

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you able to telnet it from eureka client's machine `telnet 136.144.28.122 8761`, if it does not works then some firewall rule is blocking your requests.

Comment: How will I do that from inside a Java project?

Comment: Not from the Java Project, you will have to verify from the machine/VM via terminal.